# How to choose wrap_content height of overlay on bottom of screen in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

My current Android lay-out looks like this (pseudocode)

```
<RelativeLayout width&height=match_parent>

    <RelativeLayout width&height=match_parent>
         <!-- App content here -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout width=match_parent height=wrap_content>
         <!-- These views should overlay the bottom of the screen -->
         <Textview />
         <Button />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the height of the overlay section should be the height required in order to display all the text. The button should copy the TextView's height.

I put like this:

```
button height: match_parent
textview height: wrap_content
```

but: the match_parent of the button seems to be taking the full screen of space, because the parent of it is wrapping the content ([Like this!](https://gyazo.com/8540197a331c7e581e1582479694a24f)).

If I put the TextView and Button's heights as wrap_content: I have another problem. The button's height is smaller than the TextView's height.

Does anybody have any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The button should copy the TextView's height.

You can align the Button with the TextView's Top and Bottom using the RelativeLayout attributes `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom`.

```
<RelativeLayout width=match_parent height=wrap_content>
         <!-- These views should overlay the bottom of the screen -->

         <Textview 
             android:id="@+id/textview"/>

         <Button 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textview"
             android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textview"/>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is the solution! It works great, thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of the alignTop & alignBottom properties. Just to point out: the Button's height should be wrap_content as well as the TextView's height should be wrap_content with this method.